# Use D3's pie chart to demonstrate JSON's each collections

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to build a pie chart to show how many collections in a value of each name. 
I checked out d3.layout.pie().value() can only evaluates specified array of values.
Are there any solution I can get that JSON's value size?
For exmple

```
[
    {
        "name": "json",
        "Lead": 
        [
            {"a": "aaa"},
            {"b": "bbb"},
            {"c": "ccc"},
            {"d": "ddd"}
        ],
        "Costs": 
        [
            {
                "actual": "222"
            },
            {
                "plan": "333"
            }
        ],
        "Budget": 
        [
            {
                "actual": "111"
            },
            {
                "plan": "333"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

So the data I want to map to the value would be [4, 4, 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert your json to javascript object and then you can get the length of the arrays.

```
var temp = [
{
    "name": "json",
    "Lead": 
    [
        {"a": "aaa"},
        {"b": "bbb"},
        {"c": "ccc"},
        {"d": "ddd"}
    ],
    "Costs": 
    [
        {
            "actual": "222"
        },
        {
            "plan": "333"
        }
    ],
    "Budget": 
    [
        {
            "actual": "111"
        },
        {
            "plan": "333"
        }
    ]
}
];

 var data = [temp[0].Lead.length,temp[0].Costs.length,temp[0].Budget.length];
```

and then pass the data to the pie chart.

hope this helps :)